# asp.net C# Displaying Date in Label after compare it with now dateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, label, substring

`<asp:Label ID="Label_Resaid_Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Resaier_Date" , "{0:d MMM HH:mm:ss}") %>'></asp:Label>`

and it's shows date like this (30 May 11:21:21)
but i want something like
(the DateTime from database)-(Client Now DateTime) = and show the result like
2m,2h,2d
i mean like Facebook and Twitter Post Timing

Comment: Try replacing "Resaier_Date" by a calculated value like Resaier_Date - DateTime.Now

Comment: No good
that's not working